# How to show nested relationship in TreeView

Tags: wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

Struggling with showing nested relationship in my `TreeView`. Here is the scenario:

In the database I have `Category` and `Account` tables. Each category can have zero or more sub-categories so this table has a nested relationship with itself. Each category/sub-category can have zero or more Account in it, there is a one-to-many relation between `Category` and `Account`. Simple, isn't it!

On top of my DB, I have EDMX, with `Categories` and `Accounts` entities in it and their associations as I mentioned above. For ease of understanding, I have renamed navigation properties so that `Categories` now has `ParentCategory`, `ChildCategories` and `Accounts` properties in it.

On top of EDMX, I have my ViewModel, which defines a public property named `AllCategories`. My TreeView will bind to this property. I initialize this property at the startup like this:

```
using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities())
    Categories = context.Categories.Include(x => x.Accounts).ToList();
```

Finally I use the following `HierarchicalDataTemplate` to show this stuff:

```
 <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType = "{x:Type local:Category}" ItemsSource = "{Binding Path=ChildCategories}">
  <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Name}" ItemsSource="{Binding Accounts}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType = "{x:Type local:Account}">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

This runs fine and shows categories, sub-categories and accounts in the tree, but the problem is that sub-categories show up not only under their parent category, but also at the root-level. This happens for categories of all depths. What am I doing wrong here?

Note: If I add `.Where(x=>!x.ParentID.HasValue)` in the VM, it shows only the root category and its immediate children, nothing else.

### Edit

Here's what it currently looks like. Everything goes fine up to the dotted white line (I added that line manually for illustration; has nothing to do with WPF). After that, the sub-categories start repeating with their child sub-categories. This process continues over and over till the leaf sub-categories. I believe I understand what's going on here, but don't have a solution for it. For reference, [this guy](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/458028/Displaying-self-referencing-hierarchical-data-in-a) presents a solution of the problem, but he is using DataSets, whereas I'm working with EF and can't translate his solution into my scenario.

[image]

Comment: add another hierarchical template that contains the Categories, not sub-categories. This would be the root of your treeview.

Comment: @deafjeff: Thanks. Can you plz tell what would it look like?

Comment: don't understand your problem, a screenshot would be helpful. Also you're using the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` in a wrong way, the root visual control inside it ***should be the header***, so usually we need some ContentControl in that place, not an ItemsControl like a `TreeViewItem` as you're currently using.

Comment: each `Category` has a collection of sub-categories ***and*** also a collection of Accounts, so how exactly do you want to show 2 those collections under just a TreeViewItem? Looks like you have to merge them first.

Comment: @KingKing: I added a screenshot of the current state of affairs. Plus a link to a codeproject article that addresses this issue.

Comment: the hierarchical "category" template has to be a visual child of the Categories Root, to which the TreeView is bound. If you add a hierarchical template for the root, and shift your hierarchical Category-Type template inside it, it won't appear outside / on same level of the root, and it won't appear twice in your tree.

Comment: @deafjeff: Can you do me a favour and show me the template plz? I guess you have a point here but can't translate it into XAML on my own.

Comment: correct, it's not trivial coding ..due to being busy will provide a solution in some hours as long as nobody has helped you out here :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to connect your business data by ObservableCollections and leave your Hierarchical templates simple, so that the treeview won't show duplicate entries.
The sample code shows nested viewmodel relationship and the corresponding hierarchical templates. For simplification, the Root is an ObservableCollection (otherwise you would need to add INotifyPropertyChanged here and selective ItemsSource Binding in the TreeView)

```
<Window x:Class="MyWpf.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyWpf"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType = "{x:Type local:RootItem}" ItemsSource = "{Binding Path=Categories}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"></TextBlock>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType = "{x:Type local:CatNode}" ItemsSource = "{Binding Path=Items}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"></TextBlock>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding MyRoot}"/>
</Grid>
</Window>

namespace MyWpf
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        MyRoot = new ObservableCollection<RootItem>();
        MyRoot.Add(new RootItem());
    }
    public ObservableCollection<RootItem> MyRoot { get; set; }
}

public class RootItem
{
    public RootItem()
    {
        Categories = new ObservableCollection<CatNode>();
        Categories.Add(new CatNode { Header = "Cat1" });
        Categories[0].Items.Add("Item11");
        Categories[0].Items.Add("Item12");
        Categories.Add(new CatNode { Header = "Cat2" });
        Categories[1].Items.Add("Item21");
        Categories[1].Items.Add("Item22");
    }
    public string Header { get { return "Root"; }}
    public ObservableCollection<CatNode> Categories { get; set; }
}
public class CatNode
{
    public CatNode()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; }
}
}
```

[image: screenshot of sample app]

Comment: Very elegant indeed. I later found [Josh Smith's excellent article on WPF TreeView binding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode) that I recommend to anyone who want to get up and going with WPF TreeView and MVVM. Even though that article is quite extensive, the basic idea is the same as you have elaborated. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: btw I started out with that article too! :-)